# Session login issue if i edit the username while i'm logged

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have a problem with an  login session. When i log an user i create a

`$_SESSION['username']`

To redirect the user

`header('location:profile.php?user='.$_SESSION['username']);`

The problem appears when i edit the user username in database because session doesn't match with username anymore. I tried to destroy session and create new one on update but then user appears as not logged in and in link it's same old session.

Comment: **why** are you editing the username in the database? is it something you do often or just for a particular situation?

Comment: Use the userid instead of the username.

Comment: after update set new session value like this `$_SESSION['username'] = $new_user_name;`

Comment: Instead of session variables, try using with session id

Comment: It's impossible to fix, because you are forcing the username to change and the session doesn't know that. You shouldn't change usernames through the database manually, since that's not really practical. To kind of figure out this situation, have some other way of saving the user pointer, such as an user ID like mentioned above. An altenative way is to make your own session class, which handles all sessions accordingly.

Comment: with session id it's working but i wanted to display username in link instead id=23123

Comment: If so, create session variables with name, do db calculations with session id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, you will want a unique, permanent identifier that can link up your session to your DB row. A typical row which matches this is the user ID, not the user name.

If you need the username, you can run a query based on your identifier, and continue the script from there.

Of course, there are other fields and methods to help you achieve this, but the main idea to get from this is to **not use an identifier which can be modified**. As you have already found out, doing so will cause your session and DB to be unsynchronized.

Comment: i'm gna use the id then but i wanted to display username in link instead id=232131.  :)

Comment: On your user login page, when checking for the existence of the user, pull down the row found and get the username. You can then use that to redirect to `profile.php?user=$xyz` (: